при записи данных в строку excel (openpyxl) не выполняется условия пропуска ячейки
При выполнении данного кода должна производиться запись в ячейки, но те, что указаны в skip_cells_later должны пропускаться, там стоят формулы. Однако, запись производится во все ячейки, включая и исключения.
что же тут не так?
skip_cells_later = ['i', 'q']  # Список ячеек, которые нужно пропустить
for row in gmu_svod_ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=epgu_svod_ws.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=epgu_svod_ws.max_column):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.column_letter in skip_cells_later:
            continue
        if cell.value == cell_value:
            begin_cell = 2
            for i in range(len(merged_list)):
                gmu_svod_ws.cell(row=cell.row , column=begin_cell + i, value=merged_list[i])


Думаю, что cell.column_letter возвращает букву в верхнем регистре, а вы сравниваете с нижним. Приведите к одному регистру

я тоже так думал, но нет. Проверено

Ок, хорошо, регистр влияет на исполнение, видимо из-за типа операционной системы, не знаю.
Исправил но, как ни странно, это не повлияло на результат, в этих ячейках по прежнему производится запись, вместо того, чтобы просто их пропустить.

В данном виде я не вижу решение задачи, и сделал условие по-другому:
for col_index, value in enumerate(data, start=1):
    cell = ws.cell(row=row_number, column=col_index)
    if not cell.value:  # Проверяем, пустая ли ячейка
        cell.value = value  # Заполняем ячейку значением

